# Bluetooth Device Not Working

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth

I'm trying to set up the on-board Bluetooth of the Raspberry Pi 3 (Kali running).
The Pi isn't connected to the internet, so I installed:

```
pi-bluetooth_0.1.1
bluez_5.23
bluez-firmware_1.2
```

by hand. The I ran the command:

```
systemctl start bluetooth
```

the Bluetooth device `hci0` isn't listed:

```
hciconfig hci0 up
Can't get device info: No such device


hciconfig --all
Devices:


bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# list
[bluetooth]# show
No default controller available
```

`sudo` doesn't work either.

Did I miss anything? I read that (re)installation of `raspberrypi-sys-mods`
may solve the problem. This seems to be tedious in my case due to the package dependencies.